# How to convert firestore TimeStamp in cloud function or nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

hello guys am building a restAPI with express, node and firebase cloud function and it's returning the documents from my collection successfully. But my problem is am returning the date each document was created as JSON but am unable to convert the timestamp date to javascript date.....
here is my code for clearity:

```
// Single report route that accepts a report ID and return the report
app.get('/report/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let report;
    const reportDoc = await admin.firestore().collection('corruptionReports/').doc(req.params.id).get();
    if (reportDoc.exists) {
      let reportDate = reportDoc.data().createdAt;
      report = {
        id: reportDoc.id,
        createdAt: reportDate.toMillis(),
        ...reportDoc.data()
      }
      return res.status(200).json(report)
    } else {
      return res.status(500).json({
        "status": "failed",
        "message": "invalid report ID"
      })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      "status": "failed",
      "message": "invalid report ID"
    })
  }
})
```

with the code above I basically want to return the document with the server TimeStamp in milliseconds.

Comment: I doubt `reportDate.toMillis()` is a function. Is `reportDate` a number/timestamp?

Comment: @Jonathan reportDate is the firestore timestamp object that is created when the document is created

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate

Answer (score 0):

Firestore timestamps are very useful but a bit of a pain to convert or to compare against. Here is the code I use in my cloud functions to get a Javascript date from a Firestore timestamp:

```
var createdAt = new Date(reportDate._seconds * 1000);
```

where reportDate is the Firestore timestamp field, like in your example code.

Answer (score 0):

```
reportDate.toDate().toLocaleDateString('en-US')
```

For exactly date formats, read more:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString